# Como criar uma coluna do tipo Boolean no Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Até onde sei, o Oracle não disponibiliza um *valueType* do tipo *Boolean*. Estou trabalhando a pouco tempo com Oracle e gostaria de saber qual a melhor solução para "simular" um valor true/false no banco de dados Oracle?

```
CHAR(1) (Y/N) ?
INTEGER (0/1) ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para criar segue

```
create table tbool (bool char check (bool in (0,1));
    insert into tbool values(0);
    insert into tbool values(1);`
```

Comment: perfeito! muito bom e obrigado

Answer (score 4):

NUMBER (0/1) é o padrão.

Frames como EntityFramework, NHibernate, Dapper e etc, identificam, por padrão, ao executar um comando no banco Oracle, que 0 = false e 1 = true.

Answer (score 3):

Boa tarde, DeRamon.

Pesquisei aqui e vi que tem gente que também utiliza o RAW(1), parece ser uma boa prática.

Porém, alguns defendem que pode-se utilizar o CHAR(1) ou até mesmo o NUMBER(1), e ainda pode criar uma Constraint, permitindo entrada de apenas 0 e 1 neste campo numérico.

Eu optaria pelo CHAR(1), imagino que deixará sua base de dados mais limpa e mais fácil de ser entendida.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Não tinha lido sobre o RAW. Também dei uma pesquisada antes, e por isso fiz a pergunta para saber se alguém já teve esse tipo de situação, e se já teve algum problema usando char ou number.  Até então, CHAR(1) tem sido o mais indicado. Vou aguardar para ver se mais alguém pode acrescentar algo mais. Obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 1):

Para criar um campo booleano no Oracle, você pode criar desta forma:

Crie um campo para receber o valor booleano:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name_check char(1) DEFAULT '1';
```

Quando inserir um registro, por padrão, se não for informado, será preenchido como 1.

Agora, para garantir que ele possua valores apenas como 1 or 0, adicione a constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD
CONSTRAINT name_constraint 
column_name_check (ONOFF in ( '1', '0' ));
```